# How do I get a program to autostart in Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd, autostart, icewm

The question sounds trivial, but hear me out.
I have set up Arch and added icewm to it, works like a charm with xserver.
I can start icewm with the .xinitrc file no problem, but when I add "focuswriter" right after, it will start icewm, but not focuswriter.

I checked on the icewm startup options itself. There was no startup file, I had to create one myself. Why? No clue. I added the respective command. Nothing

I tried to create an .sh file with the command and start is as a service in systemd that would run after the startx command was executed. Nothing

I tried check for different locations and quadruplechecked everything. Focuswriter runs fine, if I start it manually, either through the .sh command file, the command "focuswriter" or through the GUI, but NOT through any means of autostart, no matter what I do.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Below is the contents of my focuswriter_startup.service. Inside the file is the original username, if you were wondering.

```
[Unit]
Description=Focuswriter_Startup
After=graphical.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 7
ExecStart=/home/username/.config/focuswriter_startup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Comment: Update: I now have xdg-autostart installed and that DOES start focuswriter automatically, but now xdg-autostart won't autostart. I think, that all of this is a cruel joke.

Comment: `but when I add "focuswriter" right after` add it before `icewm` with `&`.

Comment: `startx` will not pull the `graphical.target` AFAIK (since it isn't even a systemd service). You can use `systemctl --user start` or `systemd-run --user` in `.xinitrc` though. Make sure you pass in the `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` env var appropriately.

Comment: I have now successfully managed to autostart focuswriter with xinitrc by having it before icewm and also use chmod to make it executable. I have then added Ly as my display manager and the autostart of focuswriter does not work anymore.

Comment: I suppose it gives you a switch / list for you to choose which DE/WM to start and one of the options is `icewm` and one is `xinitrc` and you chose the former?

Comment: Btw, you can add a script for this focuswriter thing (also with the `&`) to `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d` (so that you don't have to use the `xinitrc` option). Make sure it is executable (permission bits). Better with name ending with `.sh` for maximum compatibility in case you stop using this DM one day. https://github.com/fairyglade/ly/blob/v0.5.3/res/xsetup.sh#L57-L64 https://github.com/fairyglade/ly/blob/v0.5.3/src/login.c#L396-L403

Comment: I solved it by kicking my window manager out. It works like a charm now. Thanks for all your input folks!